# Reduce 'waiting' time for a GET request to API

Tags: django, angular, api, http

I am using Angular for frontend and Django for backend. I am referencing an API with particular graph data I am trying to retrieve. I think I have done it in an efficient way and have tried researching the best ways to do it. But the timings still show 5000-6000ms in waiting.

Is this because of the angular to django link before the request is actually sent? I am doing it this way as I have an authorization key I wanted to keep secure in the backend.

Code is long and in many files, I will try to explain: 
-Django get request to retrieve data for 3 graphs, this view also transforms the data into dictionaires and then returns keys and values separately as a response.
-This is all coming from the Angular frontend which calls this upon loading the page to view the graphs.

I expect/want a quick request and subsequent page loading but the page loads and then the graphs don't load for another few seconds. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: You should check timings for each step in order to determine what takes time. Use your browser dev tools to see if the actual request takes that long (or if the front-end takes time processing the response); use logging to time your views; use your shell to perform the same queries to the db and time them. Without all of this it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I am looking in the dev tools, for my last try it says all 5993ms was on 'Waiting'. I'm also not querying my own database it is to a 3rd party.

Comment: then it's the HTTP response that takes a long time to return. you should time the query to the 3rd party by itself (from your django server, assuming you call their API from within your view)

Comment: yeah the api call is in the view, how would I time this?

Comment: as a starter, I would call it myself manually with curl (or httpie) to see how long it takes to respond in normal circumstances. Or in your python view, just subtract the timestamps before and after calling it to know how long it took to respond (you can log that). You're not saying if you call it once or 3 times (once for each graph), in the latter case, I would split the graphs into their own angular calls so they can be done in parallel. Finally, add some loading indicators (spinning wheels) so the user knows the graphs are being fetched, a lot of the experience is "managing expectations".

Comment: I have used Postman and can see the call there says it takes 1996ms, so not the fastest anyway. I just felt like it had been faster than that in the past few days. It is just the 1 api call that loads 3 graphs so don't think that's the issue but I agree about the loading indicators as I already have spinners until the graph loads

Comment: there's still another 4s needed elsewhere (could be slow network). To make sure your python code isn't that slow (which I doubt), add some timing logging to your view so you can check in your console (if this is running locally) or in your logs (if this is in a remote environment) where the app spends time. These issues can only be solved by meticulously measuring time spent in each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is due to my connection speed and the size of what I am accessing, for other optimisations look at other related questions. 
Best I could offer was introducing spinners for better experience. I have been further testing and the times have been as low a 1s. 
So I don't think it is an issue with the code but my connection or the API connection.